# Normalize Javascript Termary Results so Both Arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm using React and Redux.  I have the following variable assignment which checks to see if the selectedAccount prop exists.  If so, it will grab the account_number and store it in accountNumbers.  If the user didn't select an account, the ternary statement will look at the allAccounts props and reduce that array of objects down to an array of account numbers.

```
> let accountNumbers = this.props.selectedAccount ?
> this.props.selectedAccount.toJS().account_number :
>       this.props.allAccounts.reduce(( accumulator, currentElement ) => accumulator.concat(currentElement.account_number));
```

The 1st expression of the ternary statement returns a string; while the 2nd expression returns an array.  I'm trying to get the 1st expression to return an array.  Any ideas?  I'd love to do all of this in 1 line.  Thanks in advance.  All help is appreciated.

Please note my objects are structured as follows:

```
> selectedAccount: { account_nickname: "X", account_number: "123456",
> mailing_address: "The White House" }
> 
> allAccounts: [ 0: { account_nickname: "X", account_number: "123456",
> mailing_address: "The White House" }, 1: { account_nickname: "Y",
> account_number: "76543", mailing_address: "Washington Monument" } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your ternary returns an account number, not an account.  I suspect you want to return selectedAccount (?).  And to make it a one-item array, just wrap it with square brackets, ie:

```
let accountNumbers = this.props.selectedAccount ?
   [this.props.selectedAccount] :
   this.props.allAccounts.reduce(( accumulator, currentElement ) => accumulator.concat(currentElement.account_number));
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did it!